# two problem : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3' and from token_multi_sender import TokenMultiSender

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3py

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
PS C:\Users\lukman\Desktop\token_multi_sender> python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukman\Desktop\token_multi_sender\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from token_multi_sender import TokenMultiSender
  File "C:\Users\lukman\Desktop\token_multi_sender\token_multi_sender.py", line 6, in <module>
    from web3 import Web3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3'
```

this the beginning of my main.py

```
from typing import List

from dotenv import dotenv_values

from config import Config
from token_multi_sender import TokenMultiSender
```

and this is in my token_multi_sender.py

```
import json
import time

from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from web3 import Web3

from config import Config
from utils import load_json_from_file, WalletType
```

I am already including `web3` but still have this

Comment: Use a Python environment manager (virtualenv or conda) if you are not yet. Open a python command line `python` and see if `web3` is installed by `>>> from web3 import Web3`. If you have the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3'`, then it is not installed. I use conda, so for me it would be `conda install -c conda-forge Web3` then on Python command line `from web3 import Web3` won't return an error.

Comment: then showing this like now 



```PS C:\Users\lukman\Desktop\token_multi_sender> python3
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from web3 import Web3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3'```

Comment: @ Lukman, looks you need to install web3, there are different options on how you could do that https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/